# pageblock title's text is wrapping

Tags: visualforce, force.com

The text in my pageblock title is wrapping by default.

```
<apex:pageBlock title = "xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz ">
```

How do I put it on one line? I tried making the title a child, but the font sizes were off...

```
<style type="text/css">
.pbTitle {
    white-space: nowrap
}
</style>
<apex:pageBlock>
 <b>
A very long title since it really is more like a help text to let people know what will be happening next and as such it will wrap around on the screen somehow... and so on and son on  ...
</b>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can control the break of the text using some CSS in the VF page:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .pbTitle {
        white-space: nowrap
    }
</style>
```

This will cause the text within that table cell not to wrap.

Comment: I'd already tried adding no-wrap attribute. Pageblock titles don't like that.

Comment: Please add to your question the markup which the pageblock title "didn't like". This style attribute when applied to either the `td.pbTitle` or to the `h2.mainTitle` rendered elements work exactly as you desire.

Comment: i updated the code. It prevents the wrapping of the text, but the font size was off, when the title was a child. When the title is an attribute, it works. Why is that?

Comment: The difference is the HTML that is rendered by the `apex:pageBlock` tag. The title attribute becomes an `h2` tag within the `div` that is the pageblock header while the other markup becomes a child node within the `div` that is the pageblock's body. If you are interested in adding instructional text in the pageblock body, you will need to style your own markup or leverage a pageMessage as @Ralph suggests.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to present some help text instructions to the user I find a page message tag looks nicer than cramming a bunch of text into the page block title.

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Do stuff">
  <apex:pageMessage severity="info" strength="3" summary="Instructions for want to do in this page block"/>
</apex:pageBlock>
```