# apex:outputLabel : Not able to display on top of inputField

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, pageblocksection, panelgrid

This is the code for page block section:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Search Territory Accounts" collapsible="false">
    <apex:panelGrid columns="4">
        <apex:inputField value="{!territory.Name}" label="Test" id="test123"/>
        <apex:input type="date" title="Start Date" value="{!startDate}" id="startDate"/>
        <apex:input type="date" title="Effective Date" value="{!effectiveDate}" id="effectiveDate"/>
        <apex:input type="date" title="End Date" value="{!endDate}" id="endDate"/>
    </apex:panelGrid>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

And the result is 
[image]
I am trying to place the Label on top of the input field. I have just modified the first column to see if it works but it did not.
And also each grid should look like a different block as shown here:

[image]

I tried placing output and input labels in pageblockselectionitems, but it did not work:

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    <apex:outputLabel value="Test" for="test123"/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    <apex:inputField value="{!territory.Name}" label="Test" id="test123"/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

It is still showing the output label on the left side of the input field.

**Updated**

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Search Territory Accounts" collapsible="false">
    <apex:panelGrid columns="4" cellSpacing="20" styleClass="">
        <apex:pageBlock title="Test">
            <apex:inputField value="{!territoryAssociation.Name}" id="test123"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Start Date">
            <apex:inputField type="date" value="{!territoryAssociation.Effective_Date__c}" id="startDate"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Effective Date">
            <apex:inputField type="date" value="{!territoryAssociation.Effective_Date__c}" id="effectiveDate"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlock title="End Date">
            <apex:inputField type="date" value="{!territoryAssociation.End_Date__c}" id="endDate"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:panelGrid>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this logic for `apex:panelGrid` and do not use `apex:pageBlockTable`

```
<style>
    .colStyle1 { width: 10%;padding-left:5px; text-align:left; padding-top:3px; padding-bottom:5px;}
    .colStyle2 { width: 10%;text-align:left; padding-left:5px; padding-top:3px; padding-bottom:3px}
    .colStyle3 { width: 10%; text-align:left;padding-left:5px; padding-right:10px; padding-top:3px; padding-bottom:3px}
    .colStyle4 { width: 10%; text-align:left;padding-left:5px; padding-right:10px; padding-top:3px; padding-bottom:3px}

</style>
  <apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock mode="maindetail">
      <apex:panelGrid columns="4" border="0" styleClass="tableStyle" width="100%" columnClasses="colStyle1,colStyle2,colStyle3,colStyle4">
            <apex:outputLabel style="font-weight:600">Planned Territory</apex:outputLabel> 
            <apex:outputLabel style="font-weight:600">Start Date</apex:outputLabel>
            <apex:outputLabel style="font-weight:600">Effective Date</apex:outputLabel>
            <apex:outputLabel style="font-weight:600">End Date</apex:outputLabel>
            <apex:inputField value="{!territory.Name}" label="Test" id="test123"/>
            <apex:input type="date" title="Start Date" value="{!startDate}" id="startDate"/>
            <apex:input type="date" title="Effective Date" value="{!effectiveDate}" id="effectiveDate"/>
            <apex:input type="date" title="End Date" value="{!endDate}" id="endDate"/>       
      </apex:panelGrid>
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
```

Layout will look like this (ignore about fields in the picture)

[image: panel grid]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I needed each panel grid in a box and I already have a page block in top which displays other elements so I have modified my VF code. Please see my updates, now the issue is the title is displayed in two lines.

Comment: <style type="text/css">
    .pbTitle {
        white-space: nowrap
    }
</style>

Comment: use the above style for no wrapping, refer this: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/10957/pageblock-titles-text-is-wrapping